# how to handle 500 error message with axios

Tags: javascript, axios

I cannot get the response text in the `500 error` with axios.

in Network tab in dev tools i can find the error message like this

```
{"Message":"500 error message 0","Code":0,"Type":"error"}
```

and I use

```
axios()
.then(function(done) {
   //fine and can get done.data
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
});
```

but I can only get

```
Request failed with status code 500
```

so how can I get the response text with axios

Comment: take a look https://gist.github.com/fgilio/230ccd514e9381fafa51608fcf137253

Answer (score 32):

according to [axios readme](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors):

```js
axios.get('/user/12345')
  .catch(function (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
      // that falls out of the range of 2xx
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.headers);
    } else if (error.request) {
      // The request was made but no response was received
      // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
      // http.ClientRequest in node.js
      console.log(error.request);
    } else {
      // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
      console.log('Error', error.message);
    }
    console.log(error.config);
  });
```

Comment: i use `console.log(error.message)` ,only get `Request failed with status code 500` rather than the real message in `error`.

Comment: yes as you can see from the documentation above, what you are looking for should be in `error.response.data` not in `error.message`.